# measures in infinite dimension space of entire functions

Tags: pr.probability, cv.complex-variables, measure-theory, probability-distributions

It is known that there is no canonical generalization of Lebesgue measure in infinite  dimension of function spaces. Since it seems that the space of (transcendental) entire function seems improtant in many aspects,  I do not know whether there is some measures on this space.

From intuitional guess, it seems that the of entire function with growth infinite order is much larger than the set of entire functions with finite order. I wondered is there some theories in discussing about this topic. For example, one can introduce some nice measures on the space of all entire functions and prove that the set of functions with infinite growth order is larger than the set of entire functions with finite order.

Any comments and reference will be appreaciated.

Comment: I am not an expert in this space, but for the purposes of defining random analytic functions to then study their zeroes one can take Taylor series with random (for example, iid Gaussian) coefficients. Does this sound like anything related?

Comment: @LeonidPetrov Thank you, Leonid Petrov.  I know what you mean. I am not sure whether it is related or not.

Comment: If you look at $F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A_k+iB_k}{k!} z^k$ with $A_k,B_k$ i.i.d. Gaussian then it is almost surely entire, and its order should be finite almost surely too. So it really depends on the probability space you are considering. Also, note that for any fixed entire function $g(z)$, the probability $Pr( \sup_{|z| < R}|f(z)-g(z)| < a)$ is non-zero, but it is zero as $R \to \infty$ or $a \to 0$